# negative queue size on Azure Service Bus

Tags: azure, message-queue, azure-storage

I discovered a peculiar stack-size on an Azure service queue

-0,000128746032714844 MB

When I remove an item from the queue the size decreases, I expected it to be zero when the queue length was zero. But it wasn't. I tried it a couple of times and the queue size kept decreasing.

After logout and login the size was still negative.

How can a size be negative?

UPDATE:
I just noticed I have -9,5367431640625E-06 MB as a queusize.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is exactly the issue. This is a very small number. So it may be caused by float/double precision. You can approximately say it is 0.

Best Regards,

Ming Xu.

Comment: I updated the question with more info: I have a new size -> -9,5367431640625E-06 MB Which rules out the float/doable precision as the correct answer.